# Setting redirect when accessing Cognito via sk-auth

Tags: amazon-ec2, amazon-cognito, svelte, sveltekit

I have built a Svelte application using SvelteKit that uses Cognito for authentication.  I used the following site: [Cognito authentication for your SvelteKit app](https://robertohuertas.com/2021/07/25/sveltekit-cognito-authentication/) guide me in setting this up.  The app and connection to Cognito works well when running in local development via `npm run dev`, however, when running in production on an EC2 server via `npm run build` and `pm2 start /build/index.js` it sets the **redirect_uri** portion of the Cognito URI to `http://localhost:3000`.  I can't figure out how to get it to set the redirect to my actual domain.

Here are some relevant code snippets on how it is currently set up on EC2:

**/etc/nginx/sites-available/domain.conf**

```
server {

  server_name example.com;

  location / {
    root /var/www/html/build;
    proxy_pass http://localhost:3000;
  }

  listen [::]:443 ssl ipv6only=on;
  listen 443 ssl;
  ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.com/fullchain.pem;
  ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.com/privkey.pem;
  include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-nginx.conf;
  ssl_dhparam /etc/letsencrypt/ssl-dhparams.pem;

}
```

**svelte.config.js**

```
import node from '@sveltejs/adapter-node';

/** @type {import('@sveltejs/kit').Config} */
const config = {
  kit: {
    target: '#svelte',
    adapter: node({
      out: 'build',
      precompress: false,
      env: {
        host: 'example.com',
        port: '443'
      }
    })
  }
};

export default config;
```

**/src/lib/auth.js**

```
import { SvelteKitAuth, Providers } from 'sk-auth';

const DOMAIN = 'myapi.auth.us-east-1.amazoncognito.com';

const config = {
  accessTokenUrl: `https://${DOMAIN}/oauth2/token`,
  profileUrl: `https://${DOMAIN}/oauth2/userInfo`,
  authorizationUrl: `https://${DOMAIN}/oauth2/authorize`,
  redirect: 'https://example.com',
  clientId: myAWSclientID,
  clientSecret: myAWSclientSecret,
  scope: ['openid', 'email'],
  id: 'cognito',
  contentType: 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
};

const oauthProvider = new Providers.OAuth2Provider(config);

export const appAuth = new SvelteKitAuth({
  providers: [oauthProvider]
});
```

**Expected URL when going to Cognito**

```
https://myapi.auth.us-east-1.amazoncognito.com/login?state=cmVkaXJlY3Q9Lw%3D%3D&nonce=699&response_type=code&client_id=myAWSclientID&scope=openid+email&redirect_uri=https%3A%2F%2Fexample.com%2Fapi%2Fauth%2Fcallback%2Fcognito%2F
```

**Actual URL when going to Cognito**

```
https://myapi.auth.us-east-1.amazoncognito.com/login?state=cmVkaXJlY3Q9Lw%3D%3D&nonce=699&response_type=code&client_id=myAWSclientID&scope=openid+email&redirect_uri=http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A3000%2Fapi%2Fauth%2Fcallback%2Fcognito%2F
```

As you can see, it is attempting to set the **redirect_uri** to `http://localhost:3000` instead of the expected `https://example.com`.  I'm pretty sure that there is some setting somewhere to allow it to set the correct **redirect_uri** when going to Cognito - any ideas or suggestions would be appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From what I can tell looking at the `sk-auth` module source code, `redirect_uri` doesn't appear to be a valid config option. Try setting the `host` config option in the global SkAuth constructor instead:

```js
const config = {
  accessTokenUrl: `https://${DOMAIN}/oauth2/token`,
  profileUrl: `https://${DOMAIN}/oauth2/userInfo`,
  authorizationUrl: `https://${DOMAIN}/oauth2/authorize`,
  // redirect_uri: 'https://example.com',
  clientId: myAWSclientID,
  clientSecret: myAWSclientSecret,
  scope: ['openid', 'email'],
  id: 'cognito',
  contentType: 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
};
.
.
export const appAuth = new SvelteKitAuth({
  providers: [oauthProvider],
  host: 'https://example.com',
});
```

After further browsing the source, you can also set the `redirect` option provided by the `AuthCallbacks` interface on the provider configuration:

```js
const config = {
  accessTokenUrl: `https://${DOMAIN}/oauth2/token`,
  profileUrl: `https://${DOMAIN}/oauth2/userInfo`,
  authorizationUrl: `https://${DOMAIN}/oauth2/authorize`,
  // redirect_uri: 'https://example.com',
  redirect: 'https://example.com',
  clientId: myAWSclientID,
  clientSecret: myAWSclientSecret,
  scope: ['openid', 'email'],
  id: 'cognito',
  contentType: 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
};
```

which, incidentally, is what the author uses in the tutorial you referred to.

Comment: The 'redirect_url' is actually a typo and just corrected it in my earlier comment, however, it didn't work BUT your first suggestion of setting the host option worked like a charm... thanks

Comment: @Scott possibly related to https://github.com/Dan6erbond/sk-auth/discussions/35 ?

Comment: Yes, the issue mentioned in the Dan6erbond link does appear to be related as it doesn't seem to pick up my redirect value so using the host option was the only solution that worked for me.